# Finding where these equations intercept.

Tags: calculus

Re-taking Calculus II and my mind is very foggy on math. I don't know how to proceed after setting these two equal to each other, the sqrt and square is really throwing me off.

$y = 24\sqrt x$ and $y = 3x^2$

I set them $24\sqrt x = 3x^2$ and I'm not sure how to solve from there or get both $x$'s on one side.

Comment: Square both sides then solve the resulting quartic with trivial-to-spot roots. Check that these are really solutions.

Comment: literally me LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$24\sqrt{x}=3x^2$$

$x=0$ is a solution.

If $x>0$,

$$8=x^{2-0.5}=x^{1.5}=x^{\frac32}$$

$$x=8^{\frac23}=2^{3\times \frac23}=2^2=4$$

Check that $x=0$ and $x=4$ are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Combining both equations, we get, as you said

$$24\sqrt {x}=3x^2$$
or

$$8\sqrt {x}=x^2$$
then
$$64 x=x^4$$ with $x\geq 0$.

from this
$$x (x^3-64)=x (x^3-4^3)=0$$

You can finish it by using the identity
$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) $$